# how to check if the user is authorize to access page based on its role

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I have a web application where front-end is `reactjs` and backend is `asp.net core`, I want to allow access the page based on the user roles.

I have implemented the authorization in react but for security purpose need to perform authorization on server side.

I have tried the `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` but that will not work since I am reusing the controller(common for all user) for different role and also I am not returning the view since I am working with react, so I need help in approach to implement the authorization part on `asp.net core` (role based)

Comment: This is very broad, this depends on the architecture of your app, do you have multiple entry points or one SPA? what exactly do you want to authorize? data access, data modification or view rendering?

Comment: restrict the user to access the page based on its role

Comment: The page as in sub-pages of react or each action that returns a view?

Comment: there is no view in project, we are working with js file

Comment: So that's something you need to check on client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use one action per use case for all roles, you may consider using ControllerBase.HttpContext:

```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,User")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething()
    {
        var userRoles = this.HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role).Select(claim => claim.Value).ToList();

        if (!userRoles.Any())
            return Unauthorized();

        return await GetSomethingDependingOnGivenRoles(userRoles);
    }
```

You may use also extension for that:

```
public static class ControllerBaseExtensions
{
    public static List<string> GetRoles(this ControllerBase controller)
    {
        return controller.HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role).Select(claim => claim.Value).ToList();
    }
}
```

so you can then use it like this:

```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,User")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething()
    {
        var userRoles = this.GetRoles();

        if (!userRoles.Any())
            return Unauthorized();

        return await GetSomethingDependingOnGivenRoles(userRoles);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once approach is to have different actions for each role

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public IActionResult Action() {}
```

Comment: i have tried that but on page load I call common action(called for every role so it is not specific to one role),so we cannot perform authorization until and unless we hit action related to specific role, can we go for filters?